# Discovering Bluetooth devices on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I've searched and tried everything I could, but I just can't get this to work. From all the examples I've seen, I seem to be doing the right thing, but maybe I'm missing something.

I'm trying to discover Bluetooth devices on Android and have been following the guide on the Android Developer page: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html
I can enable BT when the app starts and get the name and address of my device. However, I can't see the names of other nearby devices (supposed to show up as a toast). The intriguing part is, when I enable BT before starting the app, it actually does what I want and shows the nearby devices' name.

Here's the code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView mTextView;
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    final String status;

    // Check BT support
    if (mBluetoothAdapter == null){
        // Device does not support BT
        status = "Your device does not support Bluetooth";
    }
    else {
        String myAddress = mBluetoothAdapter.getAddress();
        String myName = mBluetoothAdapter.getName();
        status = myName + ": " + myAddress;
    }

    mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);

    // If BT is enabled before app start, discover devices
    // This is where things work, for some reason
    if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()){
        mTextView.setText(status);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, filter);
        getBTdevices();
    }

    // If BT is not enabled, enable it and look for devices
    else{
        mTextView.setText(status);
        mBluetoothAdapter.enable();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, filter);
        getBTdevices();
    }
}

protected void getBTdevices(){

    // Stop discovery and start
    if (mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    }
    mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

}

private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        textView.setText("Start");
        String action = intent.getAction();
        // If device is found
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)){
            // Get BT device from intent
            textView.setText("Device found");
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Device found: "+ device.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            System.out.println("Discovered!");
        }
    }
};

protected void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mBluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
    }
    unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);

}
}
```

Some help would really be appreciated, I don't know what else I can do.

EDIT: Forgot to mention, I have set both the BLUETOOTH and BLUETOOTH_ADMIN permissions in the manifest.

Comment: I'm confused on what works and what doesn't work...

Comment: If the Bluetooth is off when you start the app, discovery mode doesn't turn on the Bluetooth adapter. To do that, see  "2. Enable Bluetooth" under "Setting up Bluetooth"

Comment: If the Bluetooth is off when I start the app, I turn it on using mBluetoothAdapter.enable();. I tried it using the method in section 2 and the result is the same... What works: starting the app with the Bluetooth ON - the toast with the discovered device name is shown. What doesn't work: starting the app with Bluetooth OFF - BT gets turned on but no toast. Sorry if I didn't make myself clear at first.

Comment: Your if else enabled block is basically duplicate code... What if you do a simple "if not enabled, then enable" before the existing "if enabled" code. That way you guarantee to enter the first if-statement, which works. Also, I think using the Intent as the tutorial says to enable the Bluetooth is the correct way to enable it.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and the result is the same. I also changed the enabling procedure to the one described in the guide, no difference. It looks as if my code is not doing something that the Android system does when the Bluetooth is turned on... Weird.

Comment: Hmm. I'll test this code next time I get to a computer (and have two Bluetooth devices)